# How to deploy multi master Microsoft SQL Server database as IaaS or AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, high-availability

We have a vendor product, which support only relational databases (Oracle and SQL Server). Due to operational efficiency and cost, we are planning to use SQL Server. However, we have a challenge to deploy the product in Active-Active mode in two different AWS regions (East and West). Since (as per my knowledge) AWS RDS SQL Server or IaaS SQL Server always-on availability group doesn't allow multi-region writes. Also, due to latency concerns, we can not configure the product to the database in other region.

We want to have locally available database instance, where the product can read and write. Is there a way to deploy SQL Server in multi-region, multi-master, where database servers in both regions can accept write transactions?

PS: this product is end user facing, with a huge number of transactions. This product makes decisions based on user's transactional data.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Such questions aren't on topic for [so]; this is a site for programming based programming questions. Perhaps you should be asking on [sf]. (Though I recommend reading their tour first).

Comment: Posted in server fault as well. Hopefully would get an answer.